# How to access location.href of a nested frame in IE8 on same domain?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-8, frameset

My main page contains an `<iframe>` which points to an HTML file that contains a `<frameset>`. It looks similarly to the following (simplified for readability):

```html
<html>
<body>
  <iframe id="content" src="/same/domain/url" />
</body>
</html>
```

The `<iframe>` contents look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <frameset>
    <frame name="menu" src="/same/domain/menu/url" />
    <frame name="main" src="/same/domain/initial/main/url" />
  </frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to read the current location href of the `main` frame from the main page.

```
$("#content").contents().find("frame[name=main]")[0].contentWindow.location.href
```

Unfortunately, on IE8 it gives me the "Permission denied" error. This looks like cross-domain scripting prevention mechanism, but all URLs come from the same domain/protocol/port. For the same javascript code Chrome gives me the correct value (surprise, surprise).

Please note that:

- I can't use the frame's `src` attribute as the user might have already used the "menu" frame to navigate to another page (still, same domain).
- I have no control over the contents of the `iframe` pages, these are supplied by another part of the application and are unmodifiable from my perspective

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this would be to use `postMessage` [api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) which allows for message passing between different windows / frames.

On the root window, listen for messages

```
window.attachEvent("onmessage", (e) => {

    // handle message

});
```

Post a message to a child frame (`iframe` is a dom node).

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({}, "*");
```

Within the child

```
window.parent.postMessage({}, "*");
```

This allows a simplistic event-driven communication scheme where you dispatch actions in the form of messages and receive response laters
as `onmessage` events.

In your case you would have something along:

```
// within child iframe
window.attachEvent("message", function (e) {
    // IE8 does not support object passing, only strings
    var message = JSON.parse(e.data);

    // wait for a GET_HREF message
    // and respond to it with the
    // data.
    if (message.type === "GET_HREF") {
        window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            type: "GET_HREF",
            data: $("frame")
                .map(function () {
                    return this.href;
                })
                .get()
        }));
    }
});


// within parent window
window.attachEvent("message", function (e) {
    // IE8 does not support object passing, only strings
    var message = JSON.parse(e.data);

    // wait for a GET_HREF message
    if (message.type === "GET_HREF") {
        updateHref(message.data);
    }
});

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
    type: "GET_HREF"
}), "*");
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution. Unfortunately I cannot modify the contents of the `iframe` so a `frame` sending a message to the parent is not an option. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: OK, then it could be kinda hard to achieve. A hacky way to do this could be to fetch the pages, parse them into a document and look up the value of the  frames ?